# No overload matches the delegate c#

Tags: c#

> No overload for "GetSum" matches the delegate `Formula<double>`

How can i fix this error?

my delegate is:

```
public delegate T Formula <T>(T arg1);
```

Getsum:

```
    public delegate T Formula <T>(T arg1);

    class CalculatorClass
    {
        public static double total;
        public Formula<double> formula;
        public static double GetSum(double num1, double num2)
        {
            return total = num1 + num2;
        }
}
```

My code:

```
      private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxInput1.Text);
                num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxInput2.Text);
    
                Formula<double> sum = new Formula<double>(CalculatorClass.GetSum);
    
    
            }
```

Comment: You should not use `Convert.ToDouble`. Instead use `Double.TryParse` - and ensure you're handling error-conditions thoroughly.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the definition of `CalculatorClass.GetSum`

Comment: Type-parameter names should always start with `T` (and not `X`), so change your delegate declaration to `public delegate TValue Formula<TValue>(TValue arg1)`.

Comment: What is CalculatorClass.GetSum?

Comment: done editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate expects one parameter of type T
GetSum has obviously 2 parameters. Try changing your delegate to:

```
public delegate T Formula <T>(T arg1, T arg2);
```

and it will compile.
BTW, you can use built-in delegate  `Func<in T1,in T2 out TResult>` as `Func<double, double, double>`